# Update fails for a particular Unicode character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode, sql-server-2012

I am a SQL Server DBA and I got a very strange complaint that an `UPDATE` statement is failing.

```
create table #temp(id int, c nvarchar(10))
alter table #temp add constraint check_empty check (isnull(c,'')<>'')

insert into #temp values(1,N'ABC') --Success

update #temp set c=N'䬠䏊' where id=1 --Fail
update #temp set c=N'䬠䏊.' where id=1 --Success

insert into #temp values(2,N'䬠䏊') --Fail
insert into #temp values(2,N'䬠䏊.') --Success
```

I have a table with an `NVARCHAR` column and I also have a `CHECK` constraint on that column. When I update the same by appending `.` to the string, it succeeds. I tried googling this, but didn't find anything relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this post said [Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26153.sql-server-unicode-madness-n-is-null-but-not-quite-null-is-not-null-and-n-is-n-n-what.aspx), this was caused by collation problem, what you can do is set the collation as the SQL Server PM said:

> The behavior you are seeing is in fact by design if you are using the default collation for most locales (SQL_Latin1_general_CP1_CI_AS).
>
> In general, I would recommend using a Windows collation at the instance or database level, for example Latin1_general_100_CI_AS_KS_WS.

and change your code from:

```
alter table #temp add constraint check_empty check (isnull(c,'')<>'')
```

to:

```
alter table #temp add constraint check_empty check (isnull(c,'') collate Latin1_general_100_CI_AS_KS_WS <>'')
```